# Menu borders missing, when firefox from firefox website is used on kde

Tags: kde, firefox, plasma

Context menu and many other menus are not showing a border when I run firefox that is manually installed from firefox website), on kde plasma.

Borders are shown if I run in gnome, or if I run the firefox that comes with Debian Jessie.

I wish to fix this, as it is hard to locate menu, and use it, when it has no border.

Below image with and without border:

[image: This is an image of a menu that has a border]
[image: This one does not have a border, as you can see it is hard to find the menu]

---

I am using:

- Gnu/Linux: Debian (Jessie 8.7)
- Qt: 4.8.6
- KDE Development Platform: 4.14.2
- Plasma Desktop Shell: 4.11.13
- Firefox: 50.1.0

Comment: That looks like an issue with the GTK theme. Perhaps the Firefox provided by Debian Jessie is compiled with GTK2 while the one downloaded from Mozilla is compiled with GTK3. For reference, KDE uses QT, while GNOME uses GTK.

Comment: Based on @EmmanuelRosa comment I had a play with the gtk settings in `system settings →application appearance`, this had an effect on firefox, but nothing make the borders appear on the border less menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @EmmanuelRosa, I have found a solution.

1. `sudo apt-get install gtk3-engines-oxygen`
2. Go to `System Settings → Application Appearance → GTK → Select a GTK3 Theme` set it to `oxygen-gtx`

The menu is now in oxygen theme, with a glow border.
Some menus (the ones that had a border before, still have a single pixel border, some have both borders, this is probably because of inconsistencies in firefox).